# Changing the version number of an ironpython .DLL

Tags: dll, metadata, ironpython

I´d like to compile an dll in ironpython AND add some information on the file-version. In former versions (e.g. 2.7.7) there has been the theoretical possibility to do this by

```
ipy.exe pyc.py test.py /out:test /file_version:1.1.1.1 /target:dll
```

In newer versions I can´t see the feature (/file_version) anymore (also not in ipyc.exe, which is shipped with ironpython). Does someone know the way?

Comment: Which IPy release are you using/looking at? 2.7.x or 3.x alphas/custom builds?

Comment: I tried 2.7.7, 2.7.11 and the 3.4.0 alpha.

Answer (score 0):

I found the feature. At least in the versions 2.7.11 and 3.4.0alpha I found the feature in ipyc.exe

```
ipyc.exe /out:dummy.dll /copyright:dummycopyright /fileversion:1.1 /productname:dummy /productversion:1.1 <skripts>
```

Unfortunalely, it is not documented in

ipyc.exe /h

I was looking there for the feature, that´s why I raised the question.
Well, I prefer hidden features to hidden bugs. ;)